# Does one definition rule apply to dynamically loading shared libraries at runtime?

Tags: c++, c, dll, loadlibrary, one-definition-rule

If I load a dll or so library at runtime using dlopen() on unix or LoadLibrary() on windows, do i need to ensure that the symbols in the library do not have the same names as symbols in my program? Also is it possible to load multiple shared libraries that define the same functions?

Edit: I am specifically asking about runtime dynamic linking.

Comment: The ODR applies.  Weak symbols coalesce.  If the weak symbols violate ODR, Bad Things™ can happen.

Comment: The ODR applies to statically linked symbols. For example, in-process COM objects in Windows are implemented in DLLs, and most of them have a `DllRegisterServer` exported symbol. However, an app can still load several different such DLLs with conflicting public symbols because it is not statically linking to any of their import libraries, but rather relying on the COM APIs instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ODR violation when linking static and dynamic library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632222/odr-violation-when-linking-static-and-dynamic-library)

Comment: not completely yet, what i am still a bit confused about is this scenario: say i have a two plugins, both have a global variable with the same name. I will only load the shared libraries at runtime. does this cause problems on linux? what if both plugins export the same function?

Comment: It might be platform-dependent, also it might be different with variables and functions. You should make your question more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in a shared library loaded by `dlopen` do not appear in the namespace of the main program.  You need to call `dlsym` with the name of the object as a string to get a pointer to it.

Using your example of having two libraries dynamically loaded having a global with the same name:

```
void *lib1 = dlopen("lib1.so", RTLD_LAZY);
int *lib1_global1 = dlsym(lib1, "global1");

void *lib2 = dlopen("lib2.so", RTLD_LAZY);
int *lib2_global1 = dlsym(lib2, "global1");
```

Here, both lib1.so and lib2.so contain a global variable of type `int` named `global1`.  Because the `dlsym` function returns a pointer to the variable/function in question, you can handle this case with no conflict.

Comment: Similarly on win32 one needs to call GetProcAddress after LoadLibrary.